# Клонировать меню. без модулей

Tags: drupal

уважаемые профи, подскажите пожалуйста правильный(логичный и не нагружающий движок) способ клонировать меню
например я создал меню main-menu, наполнил его пунктами, это меню появилось в блоке, я поместил блок в регион. в результате в шапке сайта появилось моё меню. далее я хотел бы чтобы это же меню появилось в подвале тоже. при этом источник меню должен быть один и тот же. то есть если я через админку добавлю пункт в меню, которое находится в шапке, тот такой же пункт автоматом должен появиться и в меню, которое в подвале.
как я решил эту проблему сейчас. меню, которое в шапке я вывел так

```
<nav id="smoothmenu1" class="ddsmoothmenu">
    <?php print render($page['nav_top']); ?>
</nav>
```

а меню, которое в подвале я вывел так

```
<nav id="smoothmenu2" class="ddsmoothmenu">
    <?php print render($page['nav_top']); ?>
</nav>
```

но этот способ мне не очень нравится. так как по моей задумке подвал на сайте содержит только один регион, в который через админку я помещаю все нужные блоки(это логично и ориентировано на контент-менеджера). поэтому хардкода хотелось бы избежать

ещё недостаток моего способа в том, что id дублируются а пределах одной страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <? print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'свой id', 'class' => 'свой класс', и т.д. ))); ?>
```

Подставляем id, class, добавляем какие-то свои атрибуты.
Посмотрите includes/menu.inc  там все функции для работы меню. от этого и отталкивайтесь.